# Android LinearLayoutManager#getChildAt(int) retuns null

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I have this code

```
public class CustomLinearLayoutManager extends LinearLayoutManager
{
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChildren(RecyclerView.Recycler recycler, RecyclerView.State state)
    {
        super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);

        int childCount = getChildCount();
        View lastChild = getChildAt(childCount - 1);

        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

For some reason sometimes `lastChild` is `null`. How can it be?

As mentioned in comments, `lastChild` is null because there is no childs at all, so new question is why there is no childs after calling `super.onLayoutChildren(recycler, state);`?

Comment: There are no children, `getChildCount()` returns 0, and `getChildAt(-1)` returns `null`.

Comment: @user13 good point, i'll update answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for some reason, there are no views that have this layout has a parent. Can you post your xml?